# Is it inefficient to reverse a string by using a for loop in golang?

Tags: go

I did it like this Golang:

```
func reverseStr(str string) string {
    var reversed string

    for i := len(str) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        reversed += string(str[i])
    }

    return reversed
}
```

I'm a beginner and can't do better for now, but I'm still learning. I'd like to know is my method less efficient than the ones I saw online that use runes:

```
func reverse(s string) string {
    chars := []rune(s)
    for i, j := 0, len(chars)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        chars[i], chars[j] = chars[j], chars[i]
    }
    return string(chars)
}
```

Comment: Without knowing specifically what "the ones I saw online" are it's impossible to say if this is more or less *efficient*, but given that it operates on bytes instead of runes, it's not UTF-compatible (it will break any multibyte characters).

Comment: I don't care about multibyte characters.

Comment: Both methods use a `for` loop. :shrug:

Comment: Yeah, that's why I asked.

Comment: In this case, it's not clear what is the question (the title, at least). Code with a `for` loop can be very efficient. Or not. Depending on what you put _in_ the loop.

Comment: Any time you're curious which of two approaches is more efficient, [benchmark them](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd like to know is my method less efficient than the ones I saw online that use runes

Nothing to do with runes or `for` loop. Your method builds and rebuilds and rebuilds a string, over and over. Whereas the other one reverses the string in-place, by simply swapping characters. And the difference is only getting worse with larger strings.

```
package main

import "testing"

func reverseConcat(str string) string {
    var reversed string

    for i := len(str) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        reversed += string(str[i])
    }

    return reversed
}

func reverseSwapRunes(s string) string {
    chars := []rune(s)
    for i, j := 0, len(chars)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        chars[i], chars[j] = chars[j], chars[i]
    }
    return string(chars)
}

func BenchmarkConcatSmall(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        reverseConcat("hello world")
    }
}

func BenchmarkSwapRunesSmall(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        reverseSwapRunes("hello world")
    }
}

func BenchmarkConcatLarger(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        reverseConcat("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.")
    }
}

func BenchmarkSwapRunesLarger(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        reverseSwapRunes("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.")
    }
}
```

Results

```
$ go test -bench . -benchmem
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkConcatSmall-8           5000000           329 ns/op          80 B/op         10 allocs/op
BenchmarkSwapRunesSmall-8       20000000           117 ns/op          16 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkConcatLarger-8            30000         44877 ns/op      172833 B/op        573 allocs/op
BenchmarkSwapRunesLarger-8        300000          5353 ns/op        2944 B/op          2 allocs/op
```

Comment: The method with swap runes seems to scale _sublinearly_. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution will only work with ASCII characters, because len(str) gives you len in bytes, and str[i] also return byte. As soon as you get to deal with Unicode it will fail, because one Unicode (rune) can have more than one byte.

```
type byte = uint8
type rune = int32
```

So your second solution will work with any type of string characters.

Another example is to use strings.Builder

```
func Reverse(in string) string {
    var sb strings.Builder
    runes := []rune(in)
    for i := len(runes) - 1; 0 <= i; i-- {
        sb.WriteRune(runes[i])
    }
    return sb.String()
}
```

which is in my tests performs almost the same as in array replacement (your second example) - 3 times faster than string concatenation.

```
BenchmarkReverseStrConcat-8    1000000  1571 ns/op  176 B/op    29 allocs/op     
BenchmarkReverseStrBuilder-8   3000000  499 ns/op   56 B/op 6 allocs/op
```

Comment: If you know (or have an estimate for) the final size you should pre-allocate the builder: `sb.Grow(len(in))`.